# Resource ID # 0x0 setColorText

Tags: java, colors, resources

I have an issue  related  `Resources&NotFoundException error: Resource ID # 0x0 in line:` 
this is the second class. it extends from main.

Here's example:

```
titulo.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(colorInt));

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        colorInt = 2130968576;

        setContentView(R.layout.my_class);

        pintarElementos();
    }

    public void pintarElementos() {

        TextView titulo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTitulo);
    titulo.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(colorInt));
    }
```

Can any one tell me how can resolve this issue?

Comment: Ok, and? What are you trying to do? What did you tried? Did you searched before asking?

Comment: i  am trying change the color text when the activity start. yes i have searched before ask

Comment: A good question would be: Why don't you use a colors.xml and R.color.colorname?! (and the most obvious: why don't you use english method names like every developer should do?)

Comment: 1 - With R.color.red from colors.xml failed too- 2 -i am spanish and i write in spanish